# DataTables.js removes multiple rows on row().remove().draw() call

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

When I `row(row).remove().draw(false)` on a `row` Datatables removes an extra row.
This is my javascript:

```
$('.wrapper').on('click', '#confirm_delete', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var modal = $(this).closest('.modal');
    var id = modal.find('#delete_id').val();
    var row = $('#list_bkng_bus').find('.booking-id[value="'+id+'"]').closest('tr');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/includes/ajax/bookings-bus.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 'delete_id': id },
        success: function(result) {
            bkng_bus_table.row(row).remove().draw(false);
            modal.modal('hide');
            status_message('success', 'Boeking verwijderd');
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(error);
            status_message('error', 'Databasefout. (Remove booking business)');
        }
    });

});
```

This is the content of my `row` variable:

```
0 : tr.even
context : document
length : 1
prevObject : [input.booking-id, prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: "#list_bkng_bus .booking-id[value="57"]"]
```

So it contains a `tr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the fact that because of the way the table was generated (dynamically), multiple event listeners were attached to the element.

The solution was using `.off('click')` before `.on('click', '#confirm_delete', function(e) {`.
Which makes this code function as expected:

```
$('.wrapper').off('click').on('click', '#confirm_delete', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var modal = $(this).closest('.modal');
    var id = modal.find('#delete_id').val();
    var row = $('#list_bkng_bus').find('.booking-id[value="'+id+'"]').closest('tr');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/includes/ajax/bookings-bus.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 'delete_id': id },
        success: function(result) {
            bkng_bus_table.row(row).remove().draw(false);
            modal.modal('hide');
            status_message('success', 'Boeking verwijderd');
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(error);
            status_message('error', 'Databasefout. (Remove booking business)');
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

you code should work, and if not then you VAR row should have problem.
in case of more information you [can check](https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html)

Comment: I've added the `row` variable.

Comment: I mean to say, is you selector is perfect? Try to check in the console with static id. It'll return selected DOM